# D246A - what kind of diode is this?

Tags: diodes, identification

We have these diodes in the bell driver circuit of the local church.
[image]

On the casing it reads D246A in cyrillic. After a quick search I found this [site](https://elektromag.net.ua/en/diode-vypryamitelny-d246a-g15610482). I have not been able to figure out the diodes direction - the multimeter showed 0.7V voltage drop in one direction, it showed around 0.4V in the other. I have seen no markings on the case (the light conditions and my eyes were/are not ideal) and there is no marking on the drawing either.

Note: I was not able to remove the diodes to measure them, I had to test them in-circuit. So I might have measured multiple diodes at the same time. Because of this, I'm unsure regarding the plausibility of the measured voltage drops.

Is this a TVS or a normal diode? If normal, which end is the Anode/Cathode?

---

I do not want to post the circuit at this time, I'll ask a separate question regarding that.

Answer (score 2):

It is a normal diode, used for rectification of AC voltage to DC voltage. The [D245A](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=006ab8549faa6dd49725d7ba72260abd7bf5d8&type=M&term=D245A) is listed here as 300 volt, 10A so the D246A is likely very similar.

- To test, put meter on "Diode Check." Place positive (red) on a wire, negative (black) on the metal stud.  Nothing but the meter lead must touch the metal stud (if anything else is connected to it, disconnect to test.)  It should read as a typical diode, about 0.7v.  It's okay if it reads 0.75, 0.65, even 0.6v.  It could possibly read 0.4v, but that would be exceedingly rare for the estimated age of the unit.
- Now reverse the meter leads.  It should read *nothing*.  If it does, the diode is bad and needs to be replaced.
- All of the diodes should measure the same, or very close to it. If any one measures differently than the others (say three are 0.7v but one is 0.4v) then replace them all.

It is a rather unusual part number, hard-to-find and very rare.  Something like a Vishay VS-16F40 or 1N3892 would probably be a good replacement, but it's impossible to say without examination by a professional repair tech.